'discord.ext.commands.cog' has no attribute 'listener'
I'm making a discord bot using python and continue getting errors.
My code within the cog
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Member

class ping(commands.cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
        self._last_member = None

    @commands.cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Ping.py is ready")

    @commands.command()
    async def ping(self, ctx, member:discord.Member):
        bot_latency = round(self.client.latency * 1000)
        member = member or ctx.author
        await ctx.send(f"Pong! {bot_latency}ms {member.mention}")

async def setup(client):
    await client.add_cog(ping(client))

My code within my main
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
import asyncio

client = commands.Bot(description="Discord Bot", command_prefix="!", intents = discord.Intents.all())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("The bot is ready for testing!")
    print("-----------------------------")

async def load():
    for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
        if filename.endswith(".py"):
            await client.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")
            print(f"{filename[:-3]} is loaded!")

async def main():
    async with client:
        await load()
        await client.start('BOTTOKEN')

asyncio.run(main())

The error that is showing up
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 935, in _load_from_module_spec
    spec.loader.exec_module(lib)  # type: ignore
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\Users\user\vsPythonWorkspace\cogs\ping.py", line 5, in <module>
    class ping(commands.cog):
  File "c:\Users\user\vsPythonWorkspace\cogs\ping.py", line 10, in ping
    @commands.cog.listener()
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'discord.ext.commands.cog' has no attribute 'listener'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user\vsPythonWorkspace\main.py", line 25, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 194, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 687, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\user\vsPythonWorkspace\main.py", line 22, in main
    await load()
  File "c:\Users\user\vsPythonWorkspace\main.py", line 17, in load
    await client.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1013, in load_extension
    await self._load_from_module_spec(spec, name)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 938, in _load_from_module_spec
    raise errors.ExtensionFailed(key, e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.ping' raised an error: AttributeError: module 'discord.ext.commands.cog' has no attribute 'listener'

I tried reinstalling the discord pip file along with completely redoing everything from scratch expecting to find syntax errors or unwritten variables, along with looking online for similar issues, but have been unable to find anything that matches. If someone could please assist me, i would appreciate it, i've coded with python in the past years ago, and dont remember much. Thank you.

I was initally following a youtube tutorial that was posted a year ago as that is the most recent one i could find that overviews the cogs, and when i got the error i want to the discord.py documentation and official tutorial and all of the code seemed to match up.

Try @commands.Cog.listener()

That doesn't work. The file name is lowercase cog, and I ran it, got the same errors.

The filename is cog but the listener is part of the class Cog (see docs).

It's not commands.cog.listener(), commands.cog is the file, you need the commands.Cog class. So, commands.Cog.listener().

i see, when i ran it i only replaced commands.cog.listener() and didnt replace class ping(commands.cog):
